# adding character at the end of each string in a file

Tags: python, file, awk

I have a txt file that contains a single column of single words as such:

```
windfall
winnable
winner
winners
winning
```

I want to use the words in the file as regex strings for a mapping jobs. When finished the words should look like this:

```
windfall|winnable|winner|winners|winning
```

I need to use python or awk to open the file, place a | at the end of each and write the new content to a new file with the new character added and the column converted to a single horizontal line.

any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, don't do that. This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), ask us for help with what you're trying to do not how you want to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python you could do:

```
with open('oldfile.txt') as fin:
    with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write('|'.join(map(str.strip, fin)))
```

The `str.split` removes newlines and whitespaces, while the `join` concatenates the lines with `|`.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest is `tr`:

```
tr '\n' '|' < file.txt
```

Comment: this will add a trailing `|` and no newline at end... use `paste -sd'|' file.txt` instead

Comment: @Sundeep That's why I didn't post but the title of the question is _adding character at the end of each string_, emphasis on _each_,

Comment: @JamesBrown probably difficult to express in words.. expected output is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
$ cat file
windfall
winnable
winner
winners
winning
$ sed ':a;N;s/\n/|/;ba' file
windfall|winnable|winner|winners|winning
```

- Create a loop using `:a`
- Load the new line `N` in to execution space
- substitute the newline with pipe
- rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

In awk, if you don't want the trailing `|`:

```
$ awk '{ s=s (NR>1"?"|":"") $0 } END { print s }' file
windfall|winnable|winner|winners|winning
```

The original version with `getline` which was basically an (not even the) outcome of an awk jamming session was:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
           while(r=getline) {         # read until EOF
               s=s (p==r?"|":"") $0;  # pile it to s, preceed with | after the first
               p=r                    # p revious r eturn value of getline
           } print s                  # out with the pile
       }' file
windfall|winnable|winner|winners|winning
```

Comment: That will go into an infinite loop on getline failures. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for how and when to use getline and its many caveats.

Comment: @EdMorton What kind of situation or `getline` failure could cause an infinite loop? I (once again) read thru that link but couldn't quickly devise a scheme that would result in such. The only `getline` failure I saw in that text mentioned was _In POSIX-compliant awks (e.g. gawk --posix) a failure of getline (e.g. trying to read from a non-readable file) will be fatal to the program, otherwise it won't_. I tested it out a bit and after `chmod a-r file` both versions (with and without `getline`)  fail `fatal`ly, `getline` version with `--posix` also when trying to process a directory.

Comment: Per [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) `All forms of getline shall return 1 for successful input, zero for end-of-file, and -1 for an error.` so in that situation you'll set r to -1 and enter the loop and then next iteration getline will fail again and so on. If you're asking for a specific test case, idk I just code the call robustly (it's just a couple of extra characters) so it'll handle the issue if it occurs since per POSIX it can occur and then I don't have to worry about how it can occur or which awks will produce specific failures when it does.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok, thank you, sir. BTW, not trying to start an argument here, just trying to learn but can't take it for granted, either; I'm one of those who just have to touch the fire to believe. Also, not really a friend of `getline` but the visit on the dark side every now and then seems intriguing. `echo itsme > foo; chmod a-r foo; awk --posix '{print getline}' foo` (and some others) seems to fail before `print` actually outputs anything.

Comment: No problem. Bear in mind though, just because you run gawk with --posix doesn't guarantee other POSIX awks won't behave differently. There's some behaviors aren't defined by POSIX (e.g. what to do with `print > "foo" "bar"`) and so any awk can do whatever it wants with them and still be POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS="|" '/ /{next}$1=$1' file

windfall|winnable|winner|winners|winning
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `paste`:

```
$ cat /tmp/so.txt
windfall
winnable
winner
winners
winning

$ paste -sd'|' /tmp/so.txt
windfall|winnable|winner|winners|winning
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming no blank lines in between rows, and input is smaller than `500 MB`, then better to keep it simple :

```
echo 'windfall
      winnable
      winner
      winners
      winning' |
```

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk NF=NF RS= OFS='|'
> ```

```
windfall|winnable|winner|winners|winning
```